# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Unable to Fix this Issue

Tags: flutter, dart

Was watching some flutter tutorials on youtube and practising making some applications using flutter. The same code works great on the tutors while he runs the code but I am facing this error i.e The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. I am attaching my code. Tried adding a null check operator also but didn't work.The error occurs at line 55 that is `title: Text(myData[index]['body'])`

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"));
    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
      var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return result;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("WIFI CONNECTIVITY"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var myData = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text(myData[index]['body']),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `Text(myData[index]?['body'] ?? '')`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply but the same error occurred.

Comment: What about `Text(myData?[index]?['body'] ?? '')` ?

Comment: using this now I am getting this error i.e The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Comment: Well what is the value of `myData` ? Is it a `List<Map<Something, Something>>` ?

Comment: when I changed this line i.e var myData = snapshot.data to this line of code i.e var myData = snapshot.data as List; The issue got fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FutureBuilder

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future getData() async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return result;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("WIFI CONNECTIVITY"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var mydata = snapshot.data as List;
            return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                child: Text(mydata[index]['body']),
              );
            });
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: just want to add one more thing you missed this line of code i.e itemCount: mydata.length . Without this error was occurring

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the fix but I have rewritten the code in a different way here is the code ...

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  var _postJson = [];

  final url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/";

  void fetchPost() async {
    try {
      final respone = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      final jsonData = jsonDecode(respone.body) as List;

      setState(() {
        _postJson = jsonData;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchPost();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("WIFI CONNECTIVITY"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _postJson.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final post = _postJson[index];
          return ListTile(
            leading: Text("Title: ${post["title"]}"),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```